# Python Dictionary from another module , globals() didn't work out

Tags: python, dictionary

file1.py

```
a = {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'}
b = {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'}
c = {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
d = {'fullname':'Messi' , 'Age': 28, 'job' : 'Player'}
so on... and many more details
```

Notice : the dict variables are very different.
Task is to obtain "Age" from user input like "Name" or "Job"
for ex: user enters messi... he must get 28 as the output.

File2.py

```
from File1.py import *
#what should the code be to access the age 

user_input=raw_input("enter a Name: ")

# user_input contains the name of the person I want to get the Age
```

I have tried using globals() but it complicates my situation
It creates a List, which then has to be accessed by integer.

Is there any way to search the values inside the dict and match with IF condition ??

Comment: I'm surprised `from File1.py import *` works

Comment: @MosesKoledoye how else will you use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to do this, but you're complicating the situation.

First of all, simplify your program even more: pull the remote code into your program file, and solve the access problem there.  *After* that works, *then* you split it into a second file.

Second, if you want those items to be in a form you can easily search, do that.  At the moment, you went out of your way to separate them into distinct variables, when you obviously want to keep them together.  Do this in one of two ways:

(1) simple list:

```
people = [
    {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'},
    {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'},
    {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'},
    {'fullname':'Messi' , 'Age': 28, 'job' : 'Player'}
]
```

Now, use your normal list search methods to find the matching item.

(2) Dictionary, indexed the way you want to use it:

```
people = {
    'John Wick': {'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'},
    'Mark Zuckerberg': {'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'},
    'Will smith': {'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'},
    'Messi': {'Age': 28, 'job' : 'Player'}
}
```

This way, you get the person's record with a direct reference, `people[user_input]`.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: this is just a small example , i am dealing with 4000 lines of data in similar fashion. 
rearranging it into that format would consume a lot of time.
so , if there is any way which could simply my current situation ?

Comment: Your data are in a separate file with 4000 distinct variable names?

Comment: yesssssss !!!!!!!! and this is not the kind of data but you can relate something similar

Comment: if you change your first file named file1.py to file1.txt  then possibly it can be done

Comment: @Argus is quite correct; don't use the data in that form: read it into a dictionary or list, and use it from there.  If the data don't change, *then* you could store it as a reference, but in the preferred form.

Comment: @Argus please don't offer to turn SO into a coding service.

Comment: @Dante as my SO senior colleague has told me not to share code i respect his dignity, well for your learning i will share a small snippet and idea that will help you solve the problem.

Comment: @DanteDevilhunter: Please read and follow the guidelines in the intro tour.  Very briefly, we expect you to make an honest attempt at solving the problem first.  If you have trouble coding the data conversion, then post another question dealing with that issue, including your code and problem statement, as you did here.

Comment: well it's a free world, anyone can do anything as they please you don't need to take my permission to code or share ideas.

i too want just a snippet, i don't expect you to code everything for me.
Please just a appraoch.

Comment: updated my answer no ill feelings you will get to learn new things from here

Comment: @prune i have gone through all the resources possible to find the answer to my problem. its been more than 2 days that i'm trying to figure out the way

Comment: You've been trying to convert a single-line file format for two days?

Answer (score 0):

*try to create a backup of your file1.py as file1.txt and do operations on that very file*

sharing a small usefull snippet here

```
import re
user_input=raw_input("enter a Name: ")
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       #print line
       matches = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'', line)
       if user_input in matches:
          age = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
          print age
```

Comment: no this doesn't solve it ! please run a script and see if you can actually get and output that way... 

Sorry but this idea will fail

Comment: i haven't shared entire code plz try from print line logic by using regex lib in python ,you will definitely succeed.

Comment: regex will do what ??? find the user input from the file content !! fantastic.... then how will that solve getting my age of that user input ??

Idea is nowhere close to what i expected but thank you for trying.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code... but i wanted to manipulate data with dictionary.

Your approach doesn't solve it

Comment: you really wanted that then you have to convert string into dictionary using regex and that will too complicated man,and you are saying manipulating from file1.py its not gonna possible the way you have given data ,all dict should be inside a list to iterate and to serve your purpose.btw this code serves your purpose